# How to store array of integer in sharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have an array integer in android studio like this { 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1}
how can I store and recall it in shared preferences

Comment: Convert it to JSON String and store it as a string

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can store an array as it is.
Either you can convert it to JSON String and store it as a string.
Or you can store each element of the array individually with an ID like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences).

Answer (score 0):

Build a string out of it. Preferably using `StringBuilder`.

And, when reading, just `split()` on commas and then user `Integer.parseInt()` on all elements of the array.

Should be faster than the json route and does not require any extra dependency.

Comment: Storing `JSONArray` doesn't require any dependency